# how to slide images?

Tags: flex3, elips-studio

I want to slide  images from right to left or left to right,is it possible?
Thank's in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Short questions get short answers. See the section on [behaviors](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=behaviors_01.html) in the Flex 3 help.